# How to bypass the self signed certificate error on nodejs express and axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to send some `xml` form data to another server, when I try to do it via postman everything seems to work, but when I do it from my the server (`nodejs @15.2.1` and `express` api running on `ubuntu 20`), I keep getting an `Error: self signed certificate`.

This was not an issue couple of months ago, but nothing have changed on the code for that request.

I have tried implementing some of the solutions posted already here

1. adding `"use strict` a the top of the file
2. exporting `export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'` as global variable on my shell
3. adding `https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false})` on the `axios` request

I have even reissued all my domain certificates on the server using `cerbot` on `nginx`, but still no solution and can't really tell if the issue is on my side or on the url I'm trying to hit.

Maybe there's a different way of doing this, or I'm missing something?

My current code:

````js
const axios = require('axios')
const https = require('https')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const fs = require('fs')

const sendInfos = (model, user) => {

  const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <persons>
  <person>
      ...rest of xml
  </persons>`


  // const CERT_PEM = fs.readFileSync(
  //   './../etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.develop.xxx.be/fullchain.pem',
  // )
  // const CERT_KEY = fs.readFileSync(
  //   './../etc/letsencrypt/live/backend.develop.xxx.be/privkey.pem',
  // )

  // console.log('CERT_PEM', CERT_PEM)
  // console.log('CERT_KEY', CERT_KEY)


  const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    // cert: CERT_PEM,
    // key: CERT_KEY,
  })

  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: process.env.WEBHOOK_URL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    },
    data,
    httpsAgent,  // [ERROR]: either <self signed certificate> error
  }

  const webhookPromise = axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response in webhookPromise', response)  
      return response.data // [ERROR]: either <self signed certificate> error
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error in webhookPromise', error)
      console.log('error in webhook promess', error.message)
    })
  return webhookPromise
}

exports.sendInfos = sendInfos


The error message: 

```sh
11|xxx-backend-develop  | error in webhookPromise Error: self signed certificate
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1498:34)
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:329:20)
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:529:15)
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:933:8)
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:707:12)
11|xxx-backend-develop  |     at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:129:14) {
11|xxx-backend-develop  |   code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT',
````